# Stuck while testing authentication using nock and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, nock

I'm writing unit tests for my app which makes third party API calls. I'm using nock to mock API calls. API uses basic authentication using username and password.

Here is an unit test to authenticate user and then return response.

```
describe('Authentication tests', () => {

    it('Authenticates user', (done) => {

        nock('<MY_URL>')
            .get('/api/now/table/test_table/test_sys_id')
            .basicAuth({user: 'user', pass: 'pass'})
            .reply(200, {'a': 'b'});

        let snowClient = require('../Client');
        snowClient = new snowClient('<MY_URL>', 'user', 'pass', 'application/json', 'application/json');      

        snowClient.getSingleRecord('test_table', 'test_sys_id', (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            expect(typeof response).to.be.a('string');
            // expect(JSON.parse(response).a).to.equal('b');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

But when I run this test, nock throw following error:

```
Error: Nock: No match for request {
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "<MY_URL>/api/now/table/test_table/test_sys_id",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "host": "<MY_URL>"
  }
}
```

But When I remove `.basicAuth()` from nock, it works correctly. What am I missing here? Is this correct method to test authenticated API calls using nock?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code of `getSingleRecord`:

```
getSingleRecord(table, sysId, callback){
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var requestParams = utils.setRequestParamsWithoutBody(this.headers, 
                                                                this.auth,
                                                                'GET', 
                                                                utils.URLBuilder(this.instance, this.namespace, this.apiName, table, sysId));

        request(requestParams, (err, res) => {
            var errorMessage = this._handleErrors(res, err);
            if (errorMessage){
                return reject(errorMessage);
            }
            resolve(res.body);
        });
    }).then((response) => {
        callback(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        callback(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use nock in the it, should use it in beforeearch in the scope of describe like this, I have not tested it, I just studied it and think it should work like this.

```
describe('Authentication tests', () => {
let MY_URL = 'you url'

  beforeEach(() => {
    nock(MY_URL)
          .get('/api/now/table/test_table/test_sys_id')
          .basicAuth({user: 'user', pass: 'pass'})
          .reply(200, {'a': 'b'});
  });
  it('Authenticates user', (done) => {
      let snowClient = require('../Client');
      snowClient = new snowClient(MY_URL, 'user', 'pass', 'application/json', 'application/json');      

      snowClient.getSingleRecord('test_table', 'test_sys_id', (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          expect(typeof response).to.be.a('string');
          // expect(JSON.parse(response).a).to.equal('b');
          done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Previously I was using nock in beforeEach only, but still it was giving same error.

Comment: can you show me the definition of this function  "snowClient.getSingleRecord"